# How many points are needed to place in a $2 \times 5$ rectangle to make sure there are $2$ points with distance less (not equal) than $\sqrt2$?

Tags: geometry, pigeonhole-principle, rectangles

At least how many points are needed to place in a $2 \times 5$ rectangle to make sure there are $2$ points with distance less (not equal) than $\sqrt{2}$?

I guess the answer is $10$, but I don't have any proof. It's also trivial that the answer is either 10 or 11.

Example with 9 points:
[image: pic]

Comment: This is one of those rare problems where computer simulation would actually **aid analysis** versus **merely** providing a solution to a problem.  That is, if you ran a simulation $1,000,000$ times where in each simulation, you chose a random point, then chose a 2nd random point outside the pertinent radius of the 1st random point, and then continued the individual simulation until the entire area was *covered*, then you could see how many points the computer had selected.  Running the simulation $1,000,000$ times, you could (for example) try to beat your score of $9$. ...see next comment

Comment: The idea is that whatever the maximum turned out to be (e.g. $9$ or $10$), you could look for **patterns** in those simulations that achieved the maximum (within the $1,000,000$ trial simulations), to see if the patterns in the pertinent simulations suggested any insights to you.

Comment: @user2661923 The question is to find a minimum points and not the maximum. Besides, I don't get your idea of using simulation.

Comment: @NN2 you want to find the maximum # points that can be placed so that none of the points is close to any of the other points.  As far as the simulation is concerned, suppose that the OP is mistaken, and a placement of 10 points is possible, without any of the points being close to any of the others.  Then, the OP could examine the choice of which 10 points, and expand intuition by seeing why the pattern that was (accidentally) found in the simulation works.

Comment: @user2661923 Ok, I get that. the OP's problem  (find $n$ min such that $\exists A_i, A_j : A_i A_j<\sqrt{2}$), and your problem (find $m$ max such that $\forall A_i,A_j : AB \ge \sqrt{2}$ with $i,j \in \{1,...,m\}$) are equivalent because $n = m+1$. But of course, simulation can't be a proof (for the second problem)

Comment: @NN2 Please re-read the first two comments that I posted, following the query.  The idea is **not** to use simulation to solve the problem, but rather to aid analysis by **suggesting** patterns to explore.  In fact, it is plausible, in my mind, that the result could be that suggested patterns could trigger analysis that would then lead to a proof.

Comment: @user2661923  I agree

Comment: You can cover the 2X5 with 4 points in the middle. Use GeoGebra and it will clear.

Comment: @Moti Unclear what relevance your comment intends.  The goal is to *cover* with the maximum # of **non-neighborly** points, not minimum.  Unclear if your comment has a *hidden* relevance, re this goal.

Comment: You used the term "at least" which allow for either interpretation.

Comment: It's funny that the OP just asked the question and go away.