# 10 arbitrary points inside a rectangle with dimensions 5 and 2

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that if we put $10$ arbitrary points inside a rectangle with dimensions $5$ and $2$, there exist $2$ points $a,b$ such that $d(a,b)<\sqrt{2}$ where $d(a,b)$ is the distance of $a$ and $b$.
I hope the problem is clear.
I don't have major results to show.

Comment: and to the second comment yes there clearly exist 9 points such that each of them are atleast $\sqrt{2}$ apart

Comment: Well maybe just do the extreme case. The maximum distance between two points is $2$. (We are assuming that the length of each cell is $1$). So then, one arrives with that there are two points $a,b$ so that $d(a,b)$=$1$<$\sqrt2$. Actually, this statement should be $d(a,b)$$\leq$$\sqrt2$.

Comment: @toolfan3 Do you have a configuration with ten points which requires $\leq$?

Comment: Yes. So starting from the top, put the points as far as possible. Then eventually going around the entire rectangle doing such a process, one actually has $twice$ that $d(a,b)$=$1$, and $once$ that $d(a,b)$=$\sqrt2$.

Comment: @toolfan3 But $d(a,b)=1$ is a failure. I can easily find nine points with a minimum distance $\sqrt 2$. The question is whether $\sqrt 2$ can be attained as the minimum distance for ten points.

Comment: It is possible to fit $10$ points in a $2\times 5.15$ rectangle, so the proof of impossibility here would have to be very precise.

Comment: This was also asked 2 days ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4040735/362967). Is there a common source for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This question is equivalent to the following question:

What is the maximum number of circles with radius $r = \sqrt{2}/2$ which can be packed into a rectangle of side lengths $l = 5+2\sqrt{2}$ and $w = 2 + 2\sqrt{2}$ ?

In 1940 it has been proven that the densest of all possible equal circle packings in the plane is the hexagonal packing.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing

Comment: this is actually wrong...

Comment: @Mr.C It is almost correct - the expanded rectangle should be $(2+\sqrt{2})\times(5+\sqrt{2})$ - but restating it as a circle packing problem does not help since circle packings of rectangles are not much studied.

Comment: no. it doesnt work, you are just giving a bound. not an exact number which is what the problem asked